# Help me solve the below Logical Reasoning question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A salesman is carrying a big bag for selling a machine. In addition to the machine that the salesman wants to sell, there is some personal stuff. The weight of his machine is three kilograms and half a machine. In addition to the machine, there is a repair tool for the machine that weighs half a kilogram and one-fourth of the machine. The personal stuff weighs four kilograms minus a fourth of the weight of the machine. Finally, the salesman has some supplies that weigh two-fifth of the machine and personal stuff combined. What is the total weight in the bag of a salesman?

A. 9.87 Kg
B. 12.73 Kg
C. 15.12 Kg
D. 16.16 Kg

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Try giving a variable name to the weight of the machine, for example $w$, and converting your text information into equations.

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando Thanks for the comment. I've tried converting into equations in my first attempt. I get 16.4KG which is not in the options. Wondering if I am going wrong with any of the conversions.

Comment: @AshaPondicherry if you show your reasoning, we can find exactly what went wrong.

Comment: How much does the machine weigh?  Answer that first.

Comment: .... or how much does *HALF* the machine weigh.  Answer *that* first.

Comment: @fleablood the machine weighs 6KG and half of that is 3KG

Comment: None of the answers are correct.  But "two-fifth of the machine and personal stuff combined" is ambiguous.  It could mean $\frac 25(Machine + Stuff)$ or it could mean $\frac 25 Machine + Stuff$.  If it means $\frac 25(Machine + Stuff)$ the answer is $13.9$  If in means $\frac 25 Machine + Stuff$ the answer is $14.2$.  All the answers given have two decimal places but the fractions $\frac 12, \frac 25,\frac 14$ will number need more than one.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for the explanation, sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The machine weighs 3kg plus half a machine. So, the other half of the machine is those 3kg, and the whole machine is 6kg.

The tool is 0.5kg plus one quarter of the machine, which is 1.5kg. Therefore, the tool weighs 2kg.

The personal stuff is 4kg minus 1.5kg, which is a quarter of the machine. So, it weighs 2.5kg.

Finally, the supplies are two fifths of the machine and the personal stuff combined - so, two fifths of 6kg+2.5kg. That's two fifths of 8.5kg, or 3.4kg.

Overall, the bag holds 6kg + 2kg + 2.5kg + 3.4kg, which is 13.9kg. This is the correct answer, even if it isn't one of the given options. Alas, test writers aren't perfect.

Comment: Ahh... I was breaking my head on this! Thank you for the clarification, sir :)

Answer (score 0):

> "The weight of his machine is three kilograms and half a machine"

Well, that tells you exactly how much the machine weighs.

After all, everything weighs half of itself plus (half of itself). So the machine weighs half of itself plus (3 kilograms).

So once you know how much the *machine* weighs you know how much everything else weighs.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. In this case, the machine weighs 6KG, repair tools: 4.5KG, personal stuff: 2.5KG, and supplies: 3.4KG. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The weight of the repair tools is not correct, @AshaPondicherry. How did you get that number?

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando Initially, I've considered 0.5 ("half a kilogram") + 1.5 ("one-fourth of the machine") = 2KG but the summation leads to 13.9KG which is not in the options. Then I tried taking 3KG (assuming "half a kilogram" of a machine) + 1.5 ("one-fourth of the machine") = 4.5KG leading 16.4KG. Either of them is in the options.

Comment: Yeah, don't see how you got the tools.  Nor how you got the supplies.